# Why is there two different equal operator in this line?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am wondering what this line does? Does it means, unless `widget.note` is `not null`,
`isUpdating` will not be assigned? Or whatever please correct me, I am really confused about what is this line doing.

```
final isUpdating = widget.note != null;
```

Comment: `isUpdating` is a bool which is dependent on whether `widget.note` is null or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isUpdating` would be true when `widget.note` is not null.
It would be false if `widget.note` is null.

Answer (score 5):

you can imagine

```
final isUpdating = widget.note != null;
```

is in short of

```
if(widget.note != null)
  isUpdating = true;
else
  isUpdating = false;
```